# Boxplot : custom width in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to plot boxplots in seaborn whose widths depend upon the log of the value of x-axis. I am creating the list of widths and passing it to the widths=widths parameter of seaborn.boxplot.

However, I am getting that

```
raise ValueError(datashape_message.format("widths"))
ValueError: List of boxplot statistics and `widths` values must have same the length
```

When I debugged and checked there is just one dict in boxplot statistics, whereas I have 8 boxplots.
Cannot Exactly figure out where the problem lies.

[image: Here is the image of the Boxplot]

I am using pandas data frame and seaborn for plotting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn's boxplot doesn't seem to understand the `widths=` parameter.

Here is a way to create a boxplot per `x` value via matplotlib's `boxplot` which does accept the `width=` parameter. The code below supposes the data is organized in a panda's dataframe.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.choice([1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 30, 50, 100], 500),
                   'y': np.random.normal(750, 20, 500)})
xvals = np.unique(df.x)
positions = range(len(xvals))
plt.boxplot([df[df.x == xi].y for xi in xvals],
            positions=positions, showfliers=False,
            boxprops={'facecolor': 'none'}, medianprops={'color': 'black'}, patch_artist=True,
            widths=[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
means = [np.mean(df[df.x == xi].y) for xi in xvals]
plt.plot(positions, means, '--k*', lw=2)
# plt.xticks(positions, xvals) # not needed anymore, as the xticks are set by the swarmplot
sns.swarmplot('x', 'y', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

A related question asked how to set the box's widths depending on group size. The widths can be calculated as some maximum width multiplied by each group's size compared to the size of the largest group.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

y_true = np.random.normal(size=100)
y_pred = y_true + np.random.normal(size=100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'y_true': y_true, 'y_pred': y_pred})
df['y_true_bin'] = pd.cut(df['y_true'], range(-3, 4))

sns.set()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))
sns.boxplot(x='y_true_bin', y='y_pred', data=df, color='lightblue', ax=ax1)

bins, groups = zip(*df.groupby('y_true_bin')['y_pred'])
lengths = np.array([len(group) for group in groups])
max_width = 0.8
ax2.boxplot(groups, widths=max_width * lengths / lengths.max(),
            patch_artist=True, boxprops={'facecolor': 'lightblue'})
ax2.set_xticklabels(bins)
ax2.set_xlabel('y_true_bin')
ax2.set_ylabel('y_pred')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot with widths depending on subset size]

Comment: This solves my problem somewhat, but it creates another one. Now when I plot seaborn.swarmplot or strip plot, it somehow shifts the entire figure by 1 boxplot. [link](https://imgur.com/a/e8Fl8LW)

Comment: You can remove `plt.xticks(positions, xvals)` if the ticks are set via swarmplot. Maybe you didn't change the old `plt.xticks(range(1, len(xvals)+1), xvals)`, as that would shift the values. The means need to be plotted using the same `positions` as the boxplot.

Comment: The boxplot is at its position, but meanline and x-ticks are still shifted though [New Plot](https://imgur.com/a/GIs0XMQ)

Comment: Yes, Now it plots exactly as expected. :)

Comment: This is IMHO not exact answer to the question which was about Seaborn. But you draw the boxplot via pyplot which is kind of a hack. You don't use seaborn features here. The `widths` doesn't work when I want to use Seaborns x, y, hue arguments.

Comment: @buhtz  Indeed, a more "exact" answer would be: the `widths`parameter is not supported in seaborn. If you also want to include `hue`, it would be even much less evident how to support hue dodging and still get a nice plot, both avoiding overlapping boxes and boxes too far apart.